# How to setup Dockerfile with WORKING dir which is external on the server disk

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have dockerfile that defining working dir to be internal,
I like it to be external, a real path in the server
this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes \"true\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90assumeyes

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        curl
       

WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh

CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

I want WORKDIR to be in my server path like for example :

```
/home/foo/my_workingdir
```

How can it be configured?

Comment: If the main goal of your program is to access and modify files in the host system, an isolation system like Docker isn't a good match for it.  Using an OS-native packaging system (like Debian's `dpkg` or Homebrew) or language-native packaging options (Python virtual environments, Node's local `node_modules` tree) would be a better option.

Comment: The working directory should ideally be a directory inside the container itself - [WORKDIR reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir).
It's like 'cd'ing into your project folder before working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

What you *can* do, is mount the directory from the host to any directory in the container.

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v /home/foo/my_workingdir:/azp your_image
```